# Gradle Project Sync Failed on Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to Android App development.I installed Java Development Kit andAndroid Studio v 3.0.1 . There was no problem in downloading and installing Android Studio. The problem came when the time came to creat a new project. My instructor on the course told me the new project would take time to set up and configure. Mine took some 115 minutes. And after it came a Windows Alert Message mentioning that Windows Firewall has blocked some features of JDK library.

This is the screen shot of the Windows Alert Message.

[Windows Alert Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npqFC.png)

I just ignored the message, and clicked the Close button.
And when I see my newly opened project on Android Studio, I see the message that
Gradle Project sync failed.Basic functionlity will not work properly.

This is the  screenshot of Gradle Error.
[Gradle Project Sync Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TIbT.png)

I am clueless about what this Gradle is. Does this gradle error have anything to do to do with the Windows Alert Message I ignored? How can I fix this problem?
I want to create apps and just new to Android App development.

Comment: you need to insatll missing sdk .. kust click on the error message showing "Install missing paltform and synch"

Comment: I installed missing sdk and there was a message.. design editor univailable until sucessful build ..I tried  syncing project..same message shows up...plus there's an error......Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Comment: add build.gradle of your app in your question

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall automatically blocked Internet access for Android Studio and informed you about that in that dialog. Most programs, like Android Studio need Internet access, so in the future you want to click "Allow access" button whenever that dialog show up (for trusted software).

Go to Windows Firewall and in the "Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall" option look for **"OpenJDK Platform binary"** and check both checkboxes.

[Screenshot tutorial](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configure-windows-firewall-allow-firefox-access), but for Firefox

Comment: Is ignoring the Windows Alert message the reason behind the Gradle Error message in my project?

Comment: Well, Gradle is complaining that you don't have platform for Android 8.0 installed, but Android Studio needs to have Internet access to download  this. So first, unblock it in firewall as I wrote in the answer and then click "Install missing platforms..." in that Gradle message.

Comment: I installed Missing platform aafter unblocking Open JDK in firewall. After that came another error. Design Editor is unavailable until successful build. I installed and sync build but that didnt work out as well..

Comment: Try restarting Android Studio

Comment: I tried restarting Android Studio there's still a message : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details. This showed up after I had Synced my project

Comment: Can you show me your build.gradle file (that one in "app" module)

Comment: Which one? the app file? or another one?..send me your email address..no screenshots allowed in comments